# Pivot Daily Time Series to Rows of Weeks in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas timeseries:

```
days = pd.DatetimeIndex([
                    '2011-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-04T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-05T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-06T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-07T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-08T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-11T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-12T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-13T00:00:00.000000000', 
                    '2011-01-14T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-18T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-19T00:00:00.000000000',
                    '2011-01-21T00:00:00.000000000',
                   ])
counts = [85, 97, 24, 64, 3, 37, 73, 86, 87, 82, 75, 84, 43, 51, 42, 3, 70]
df = pd.DataFrame(counts,
                  index=days,
                  columns=['count'],
                 )
df['day of the week'] = df.index.dayofweek
```

And it looks like this:

```
            count   day of the week
2011-01-01  85      5
2011-01-02  97      6
2011-01-03  24      0
2011-01-04  64      1
2011-01-05  3       2
2011-01-06  37      3
2011-01-07  73      4
2011-01-08  86      5
2011-01-09  87      6
2011-01-11  82      1
2011-01-12  75      2
2011-01-13  84      3
2011-01-14  43      4
2011-01-16  51      6
2011-01-18  42      1
2011-01-19  3       2
2011-01-21  70      4
```

Notice that there are some days that are missing which should be filled with zeros. I want to convert this so it looks like a calendar so that the rows are increasing by weeks, the columns are days of the week, and the values are the count for that particular day. So the end result should look like:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   0   0   0   0   0   85  97
1   24  64  3   37  73  86  87
2   0   82  75  84  0   0   51
3   0   42  3   0   70  0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create weeks number based on day of the week  
df['weeks'] = (df['day of the week'].diff() < 0).cumsum()  

# pivot the table
df.pivot('weeks', 'day of the week', 'count').fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: In week 0, the first five days (0-4) have a zero count. Is there a way to shift everything so the sixth day is first? If I convert this DF to a numpy array and then flatten it then it will have zeroes padded at the beginning and end but I would like it to be the same length as the number of rows as in the original DF. I plan to apply some transformations to this pivoted table.

Comment: You can always reorder the columns by passing your column names. `new_df[[6,0,1,2,3,4,5]]` will put the seventh column as the first one. Is this what you mean?